# Не понимаю, как работают внешние ключи

Tags: mysql, связь

Есть проблема, видимо с пониманием принципа работы внешних ключей. 
Есть бд `blog` с двумя таблицами - `users` (где собраны логин, пароли и пр.) и таблица `persons` (где собираются посты людей, статусы, популярные теги и пр.) Главной таблицей является users, дочерней - persons. Я связал два поля - `user_id` (главный) и `person_id` (дочерний). И я хочу, чтобы при регистрировании пользователя в таблице persons был **точно такой же** `person_id`, чтобы все статусы, посты, карма и прочая чухня была с одним айдишником. В чем проблема? Я неверно понимаю суть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполняю обычными `UPDATE` в разные таблицы. В таблицу `users` данные логина, пароля, а в таблицу `persons` пихаю путь до аватарки

Comment: Внешний ключ препятствует вставки, обновлению, удалению неверных данных. Если у вас в одной таблице есть только запись с user_id=1, то во вторую таблицу вы не сможете ставить связанную запись с person_id=2, например. Или вы пытаетесь удалить запись user_id=1, когда есть связанная запись с person_id=1. В это случае mysql не даст вам это сделать из-за правила `ON DELETE RESTRICT`

Comment: Немного не понял объяснения( А что мне сделать нужно, чтобы это поправить? Сейчас у меня связываются не те вещи. Т.е. с `user_id=5` свзывается  `person_id=3`

Comment: А правильные значения в поле связывания - это забота не внешнего ключа, а того, кто вносит данные. Внешний ключ не позволит записать НЕСУЩЕСТВУЮЩЕЕ. Однако он никак не отреагирует на существующее, но (по мнению записывающего) неправильное.

Comment: А как тогда записывать, чтобы они были одинаковые?

Comment: Ясно же как. Явно указывать значение person_id